# Sending a Push Notification from an app using urban airship in titanium appcelerator

Tags: notifications, titanium, push, appcelerator

Hi I am just wondering if anyone knows any architectural ideas on how to send out a push notification from my iPhone app itself using Urban Airship as my push provider in titanium appcelerator.

Basically I am supposed to create a chat system to communicate 2 iPhones with a another. However, I was told push notifications is the way to go about.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have a Urban Airship account and register your application. For the devices comunicate with Urban Airship you will need the Application Key and the Application Secret.

When a device starts your application you should register him for push notifications to be able to get push notifications using Titanium.Network.registerForPushNotifications. You can follow this [tutorial](http://urbanairship.com/blog/2010/05/26/appcelerator-and-urban-airship/).

These are the basics, and this should be enough for a simple scenario, but you might want a central place where you manage which users are logged so they don't try to chat with someone that is offline.